# tried changing a field name in my database and got an error

Tags: mysql, eclipse

[image]

I have a forum database with two tables, posts + topics, I tried changing the field names from `topic_id` to `photo_id`, but I got

> "unknown topic_id in field list

[image]

Here is my second table

[image]

Am I getting this error because of the foreign key appearing in the second table?

and for the record i am working with code too so

changing my topic_id to photo_id would mean i'd have to change all the code to   topic_id to photo_id  on every page right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change the id column you have to change first of the main column table, and then the other table.

```
alter table database.yourMainTable
    change column topic_id photo_id int(11) not null auto_increment
```

Then you have to drop the constraint foreign key of your second table It's important do that and change the column name.

```
ALTER TABLE database.yoursecondtable
  DROP FOREIGN KEY yourSecondTable,   -- if you don't know you can check it with you phpadmin.
  CHANGE COLUMN topic_id photo_id int(11) not null auto_increment --the type of both columns have to be same
```

And finally add the constraint and the reference to the first table ;)

```
ALTER TABLE database.yoursecondtable
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_yourconstraintforeignkey
    FOREIGN KEY (newid) REFERENCES gimnasio.planes(idnew)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
```